# How to write sql query for this

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
**CategoryMaster**

CategoryId Category Name

1   ABC

2   Xyz

3   PQR

**Product master**

ProductId   Name    

1       ABCD    

2       WXYZ    

3       UVWX    


**ProductCategory**

ProCatID    ProductId               CategoryId

1       1       1

2       1       2

3       2       3

4       3       2

5       3       3



**ProductDetail**

ProductDetailId Price   Qty      Date       ProductId

1       250 8   2-11-2011   1

2       200 10  2-12-2011   2
```

I want to featch all product detail from product master table with its category my table structure is same as above

Comment: @user350140, you should do yourself a favor and normalize the `Product master` table. It's (almost) never a good idea to concatenate foreign key's into one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ProductMaster table is **not normalized**. This is not good: you should model like this:

```
Productmaster
 - productid 
 - name

ProductCategories:
 - productid
 - categoryID
```